# Chrome how to get the current tab's id?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab)｛
  alert(tab.id);
});
```

Is `tab` an object? Why doesn't it have an `id` property?

How can I get the `id` of the current tab?

Comment: Have you looked at these? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Could you give me an example?

Comment: Are you running this code from the context of a chrome extension? This code won't work unless it's running from a chrome extension with `"permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ]`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts How can i get the current tab's id?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm new here and i'm new to learn this,thanks for your patience!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The "tabs" permission is only necessary for reading private informate, url, title, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){ console.log(JSON.stringify(tab,null, 2)); })` gives me next

```
{
  "active": true,
  "audible": false,
  "favIconUrl": "chrome-extension://eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl/img/favicon.png",
  "height": 853,
  "highlighted": true,
  "id": 5280,
  "incognito": false,
  "index": 0,
  "mutedInfo": {
    "muted": false
  },
  "pinned": false,
  "selected": true,
  "status": "complete",
  "title": "Tabs Outliner",
  "url": "chrome-extension://eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl/activesessionview.html?type=main&focusNodeId=5220&altFocusNodeId=5046&scrollToViewWinId=5046",
  "width": 400,
  "windowId": 5279
}
```

List of all props you can find at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab  --- **id marked as optional**

> The ID of the tab. Tab IDs are unique within a browser session. Under some >circumstances a Tab may not be assigned an ID, for example when querying >foreign tabs using the sessions API, in which case a session ID may be present. >Tab ID can also be set to chrome.tabs.TAB_ID_NONE for apps and devtools >windows.

That's important if you try run code from console

> Tab ID can also be set to chrome.tabs.TAB_ID_NONE for apps and devtools >windows.

Comment: Consider replacing your screenshot with the text content of `JSON.stringify(tab, null, 2);` or something.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be the only one possible method. I use it like this:`chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
   function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { url: "link"});
   }
  );`