# How do I get the current tab id using console in chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am new to Javascript & I want to get the ID of the currently opened tab of google chrome browser, using the console of chrome developer tools. I tried the code below, but got an exception. How do I make this work ? Do I have to learn something more just for this little thing ?

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){ console.log(
JSON.stringify(tab,null, 2)); });
```

Exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined(…)
VM1201:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined(…)
```

Source: [Chrome how to get the current tab's id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507522/chrome-how-to-get-the-current-tabs-id)

**EDIT:**
These dont not work either and fail due to the same "undefined" error.

[how to get current tabId from background page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303452/how-to-get-current-tabid-from-background-page)

[How can I get the current tab URL for chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132018/how-can-i-get-the-current-tab-url-for-chrome-extension)

Comment: Hello, i think you can find the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script

Comment: @Redrif - there is no answer in that page, no clues, no tutorial and no working code.

Comment: _chrome.tabs is only available in background scripts and popup scripts.

If you wanna to use chrome.tabs then pass message from content_script to background script and play with chrome.tabs_ 
And also there is this link : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi
Your problem is, that there is no property tabs in your chrome object.

Comment: @Redrif - "pass message from content_script to background script". How do I do that ? What is content_script ? 

Content scripts - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts ???

Comment: I just gave you link where you can read all about content scripts and what they do. Do you want a working code example?

Comment: @Redrif - Thanks for the link. Looks like its only for developing extensions. Seems that I cannot do what I want using the console. Can I do it by injecting javascript into a tab ?

Comment: I think this will only work with scripts injected **by** an extension

Comment: @AnimiVulpis - Is it a good idea to make a simple extension only to get the current tab id ? I want to get the current tab id so that I can automate testing of a chrome extension as mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647629/how-do-i-automate-browser-extension-testing-with-selenium

Comment: I think you could write an extension that can give you the tab id of the open tabs. **But** I am not sure if this will work with tabs created by another extension (guessing this is important to you because of your other question)