# Using express session how can I differentiate between different tabs

Tags: node.js, session

When I create a session store I get one sessionID per browser instance. For instance when I call req.sessionID it returns the session id for that browser instance, but I am trying to pair the session with the socket to send data from the server to the client. For ever new tab a different unique socket id is created but the session id stays the same. Is there a way to tell which tab is which using the [express session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)?

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is, but have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507522/chrome-how-to-get-the-current-tabs-id

Comment: @johnanderson did you figure out a way to solve this problem